# Chrome extension: can devtools panel receive one-time messages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, message, message-passing

In my code for devtool.js I am listening to one-time messages like this:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("TT's Automatron", "devtool/icon.ico", "devtool/panel.html",
  function(panel) {

    var panelconsole; 

    panel.onShown.addListener(function tmp(panel) {

        panel.onShown.removeListener(tmp); 
        panelconsole = panel;

        // this works
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'get-status'}, function(response) {
          panelconsole.write_queue(response.globalstatus);
        });;

        // this does not work - cannot listen to the same messages from popup.js 
        // as I do it in background.js
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {    
          alert();
        });    
    });    
  }
);
```

In the code I can send one-time message but cannot listen to one-time messages. `Alert()` is never triggered, even if messages are sent. In background script I can listen to the messages without problems by `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()`, so why not in devtools?

I was reading [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) but there is not a receiving of one-time message shown, only session connection. Does it mean it is not possible?

---

In **background** script I am listening to the same messages and there it works:

```
// listening to the same messages as in devtools panel
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

  alert('This works');

  switch(request.type) {

    // recognising different messages
    case "start-tron":    
      //  ..some code..       
      sendResponse({globalstatus: globalstatus});

      break;
   }
});
```

---

The messages are coming from **popup** script:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "start-tron", tabid:tabs[0].id});
});
```

---

Maybe I should mention that there is also an open long-lived session connection between background and **devtools**:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: 'automatron_console'});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(item) {
    // if reference exists - panel is open
    if (panelconsole) {
      panelconsole.write_log(item);
    }
});
```

---

So why can't I listen to the messages from popup in devtools.js as I do it in background.js?

Comment: `alert` might be blocked, use proper debugging: detach devtools first (dock side = "float" in three-dot settings icon), invoke devtools-for-devtools by pressing Ctrl-Shift-I, now you can set breakpoints manually or use `debugger` statement in your code.

Comment: I sat few breakpoints, but it does nothing - script runs without break and in devtools-for-devtools I see nothing, just my breakpoints.

Comment: Can you add your background page scripts to the post so we can see what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) is not directly noted, that it is not possible to receive one-time messages in a devtools panel, however there is only long-lived connection mentioned so I suppose that
 **one-time messaging is not supported for devtools**.

It seems that sending one-time messages is possible, as shown in the script above, but not receiving.

**We can only use long-lived connection:**

```
// creating communication port in devtool script
var devtools_connection = chrome.runtime.connect({name: 'devtools_connection'});

// listening to the port messages
devtools_connection.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  // sending response back to what sent this message
  sendResponse('some response');
});

// sending messages to the port
devtools_connection.postMessage({msg: 'some message'});
```